# How to use php-markdown from pear?

Tags: php, pear, markdown

I know how to use php-markdown by loading it manually, but decided to install it through pear. Installed with the following commands:

```
pear channel-discover pear.michelf.com
pear install michelf/MarkdownExtra

>> install ok: channel://pear.michelf.com/MarkdownExtra-1.2.5
```

The problem is that I have no idea on how to use it when installed from pear and the documentation does not informs anything about it, so I think it might be a pretty dumb question.

Here is how I tried to use it:

```
if(class_exists('MarkdownExtra_Parser')){
    $m = MarkdownExtra_Parser();
    $html = $m->transform($string);
}
```

and:

```
$html = Markdown($string);
```

anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it's installed OK, it gets installed into the base PEAR directory - which should be in the include path.

```
<?php
require_once 'markdown.php'
$mdtext= "... markdown text ...";
echo  Markdown($mdtext)

$parser = new MarkdownExtra_Parser;
echo $parser->transform($mdtext);
```

will output the two sets of HTML based on the contents of $mdtext.

There are some instructions on http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/